# Design Exchange mailboxes

Tags: exchange-2010, mailbox, distribution-lists, groups

I would like to have the following functionality in Exchange 2010 on SBS2011.

- department mailboxes dep1@domain.com, dep2@domain.com
- personal mailboxes user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com etc.
- avoid using distribution lists for duplicate emails

Scenario

- user1, user2 are part of dep1, user3, user4, user5 part of dep2
- user1 and user2 should see both mailboxes (user1 and dep1) or (user2 and dep1) mailboxes
- outgoing mail for dep1 should be sent from dep1 and not user1
- outgoing mail for user1 should be sent from user1 mailbox

I would like to know how to configure mailboxes and Exchange in order to have this scenario working.

Comment: You've made a fine statement but haven't actually asked a question. Should we infer by your statement that you're asking how to go about setting this up?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to setup mailboxes and Exchange to get the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail enable a public folder for each department and set the appropriate permissions.  Users can then email as themselves or the shared address.